# How do I get my wired Xbox360 Controller working with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wired, xbox-360

I can't get my wired Xbox360 Controller to work with Ubuntu 16.04. When I plug it in the light on the controller just keeps flashing, and unplugging and then plugging it back in doesn't help either. I have tried all the guides but they are for wireless controllers hence they don't work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Just having a look at the related questions you can see many regarding WIRED controllers. If you have tried that many things it would be helpful if you would explain that further and state why it did not work.

Comment: Please post what you have done so far!

Comment: I followed multiple WIRED tuts but they all ended up installing wireless drivers instead of WIRED. When I finally had the light showing 1 static light on the controller it still didn't work. All of the games are officially supported by a controller. This controller in fact. I need to know how to install the WIRED USB Drivers. I don't know why it didn't work other than the drivers being for a Wireless Xbox 360 controller receiver.